# Android Search with Multiple words

Tags: android, searchview

I have to implement the multiple search query, how to achieve it , I know the basic idea of filtering the text with the search view but not getting the idea how to search with multiple string ,I am attaching the snapshot show it will make you feel better to get an idea.

I am loading the data from the webserver.[image: Click Here to see]

TruckInfo columns are:

- Name of the truck
- Total capacity (is the capacity of the truck)
- Status Free/Busy (is the status of the truck which is currently all truck is free)
- Free location (is the where truck is going to free).

[image: Here is search implementation i have to do]

Now as in snapshot second i have to filter this data , I had searched in the capacity column --> 10 tonnes to 45 tonnes, status is--> free , free location is -->CV , from 7wed2016 to 20 Fri 2016 and then i hit search button .

Expected output should not show any result because:

1. 10 tonnes to 45 tonnes there is 2 truck ..which is right. as data coming from server
2. status of both the truck is free, which is right
3. Free location is CV that I searched, but as you can see both truck have free location mumbais, chandigarh, so this condition is false so overall search should show no data

My Try:

```
filter_search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Log.e("filter_search","filter_search");
                Localytics.tagEvent("Trucks Search Screen");
                if(frmcap.getText().toString().length()==0){
                    frmcap_val=0;
                    cap_bool=1;
                }
                else
                {
                    frmcap_val=Integer.parseInt(frmcap.getText().toString());
                    cap_bool=0;
                }
                if(tocap.getText().toString().length()==0) {
                    tocap_val=0;
                    cap_bool = 1;
                }
                else {
                    tocap_val=Integer.parseInt(tocap.getText().toString());
                    cap_bool=0;
                }
                if(from_loc_text.getText().length()==0)
                    loc_bool=1;
                else
                    loc_bool=0;

                if(frm_date_value.length()==0 || to_date_value.length()==0)
                    date_bool=1;
                else
                    date_bool=0;

                if(free.isChecked())
                    status_value="true";
                if(busy.isChecked())
                    status_value="false";
                if(any.isChecked())
                    status_value="any";
                if(!any.isChecked()&&!free.isChecked()&&!busy.isChecked()){
                    Log.e("@@inside","inside");
                    status_value="-default value";
                }


                if(!any.isChecked()&&!free.isChecked()&&!busy.isChecked())
                    status_bool=1;

                if(search.getText().length()==0)
                    loc_search_info=1;
                else
                    loc_search_info=0;

                try {
                    if(status_value!=null && status_value.length()>0 && !status_value.equalsIgnoreCase("any")){
                        truckadapter.advanceSearchFilter(status_value,"checkBox");
                        list_mytrucks.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }else if(status_value!=null && status_value.equalsIgnoreCase("any")){
                        list_mytrucks.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }else if(frmcap.getText().toString()!=null && frmcap.getText().toString().length()>0){
                        truckadapter.advanceSearchFilter(frmcap_val+"","capacity");
                        list_mytrucks.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }else if(tocap.getText().toString()!=null && tocap.getText().toString().length()>0){
                        truckadapter.advanceSearchFilter(tocap_val+"","capacity");
                        list_mytrucks.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }else if(current_location.getText().length()>=0){
                        truckadapter.advanceSearchFilter(current_location.getText().toString(),"freeLocation");
                        list_mytrucks.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }else if(fromdt.getText().length()>=0){
                        truckadapter.advanceSearchFilter(current_location.getText().toString(),"dateStamp");
                        list_mytrucks.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }else if(todt.getText().length()>=0){
                        truckadapter.advanceSearchFilter(current_location.getText().toString(),"dateStamp");
                        list_mytrucks.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    view_advance_search.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        });
```

Here is searchFiletring in getViewMethod:

```
public void advanceSearchFilter(String constraint,String tag) throws JSONException {
            items.clear();
            if(constraint.isEmpty()){
                items.addAll(advanceSearchArrayList);
            } else{
                constraint = constraint.toUpperCase();
                for(int i=0;i<advanceSearchArrayList.size();i++){
                    JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(advanceSearchArrayList.get(i).getVehicle()));
                    if(tag.equalsIgnoreCase("capacity")){
                        int truckCapacity=Integer.parseInt(constraint);
                        if(Integer.parseInt(jsonData.getJSONObject("type").getString("capacity").toUpperCase())>=truckCapacity){
                            items.add(advanceSearchArrayList.get(i));
                        }
                    }
                    if(tag.equalsIgnoreCase("checkBox")){
                        if(advanceSearchArrayList.get(i).getFree().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)){

                            items.add(advanceSearchArrayList.get(i));
                        }
                    }
                    if(tag.equalsIgnoreCase("freeLocation")){
                        if(advanceSearchArrayList.get(i).getFree().toUpperCase().equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                            Log.e("getFree_loc",""+advanceSearchArrayList.get(i).getFree_loc());
                            if(advanceSearchArrayList.get(i).getFree_loc().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)){
                                items.add(advanceSearchArrayList.get(i));
                            }

                        }

                    }
                   if(tag.equalsIgnoreCase("dateStamp")){
                       SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                       Date date = null;
                       try {
                           date = formatter.parse(constraint);
                       } catch (ParseException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                       try {
                           if(formatter.parse(advanceSearchArrayList.get(i).getFree().toUpperCase()).before(date) ){
                               items.add(advanceSearchArrayList.get(i));
                           }
                       } catch (ParseException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }

                   }


                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to still explicitly compare each filter to property of each object to see if it matches or not.

Just an idea for flow:

1. Make a class for filter input. when user clicks search button, assign all filter values to that class.
2. Make a method inside model class, that returns true if any of the filter value matches. That takes filter class object as argument.
3. Now when user clicks search button, iterate over each object in array. Call this method. If it returns true, add this object in new filter array.

Use that filter array to show search results.

### Example Code

```
///////// Filter class
class FilterTrucks {

String location;
int capacityStart;
int capacityEnd;
Arraylist<String> availability;

}

////// You model class
class Mytrucks {

String name;
String location;
int capacity;
String availability;

boolean matchFilter(FilterTrucks filter) {

boolean locationMatch = filterMatchesLocation(filter);
if(locationMatch)
return true;

boolean matchCapacity = filterMatchesCapacity(filter);
if(matchCapacity)
return true;

return false;

}

boolean filterMatchesLocation(FilterTrucks filter)  {
return location.contains(filter.location);
}

boolean filterMatchesCapacity(FilterTrucks filter)  {
return  (capacity >= filter.capacityStart ||  capacity <= filter.capacityEnd)
}

////////// Your activity

Arraylist<Mytrucks> filterArray = new Arraylist<>();

filter_search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

//create filter object from user selected fields
FilterTrucks filter = new FilterTrucks();
filter.location = txtLocation.getText().toString(); //for example

for(Mytrucks truck : arraylist) {
if(truck.matchFilter(filter)) 
    filterArray.add(truck);
}
    }
});

//use filter array to populate recycler view
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i got your idea but there is little confusion